# Request for online reference to Moduno's "Fibered spaces, jet Spaces and connections for field theories"

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

Does anyone know of an online source for Modugno's paper

> Fibered Spaces, Jet Spaces And Connections For Field Theories.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that it is in a [proceeding](http://inspirehep.net/record/186984?ln=en).